# Is there a way to backup / restore value across a scope in c#?

Tags: c#

In C# I'd like to be able to restore an object to its original value at the end of a scope. In a similar way to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822788/raii-object-for-restoring-previous-value) but for C#.

One answer on that question suggests using boost's [state_saver](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/state_saver.html) which I believe uses RAII to backup and restore the original value.

You can get RAII in c# by implementing IDisposable.

This is one attempt. It's not quite working because when you set the RefObject to a new value it just loses the reference to the original value. And you can't use it on POD's.

**Doesn't Work**

```
public class State_Saver<T> : IDisposable
{
    public State_Saver(ref T obj, T newValue)
    {
        RefObject = obj;
        m_Backup = RefObject;

        RefObject = newValue;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        RefObject = m_Backup;
    }

    private T RefObject;
    private T m_Backup;
}
```

I **can** get it to work if I add a requirement that the T object is wrapped in some kind of Wrapper class.  But it's a bit more *weight* than I'd like to impose on someone using the class.

**Works**

```
public class ValueWrapper<T>
{
    public ValueWrapper(T value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class ScopedBackup<T> : IDisposable
{
    public ScopedBackup(ref ValueWrapper<T> obj, T newValue)
    {
        RefObject = obj;
        m_Backup = RefObject.Value;

        RefObject.Value = newValue;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        RefObject.Value = m_Backup;
    }

    private ValueWrapper<T> RefObject;
    private T m_Backup;
}
```

Usage:

```
ValueWrapper<bool> fred = new ValueWrapper<bool>(true);

Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes true

using (new ScopedBackup<bool>(ref fred, false))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes false
}

Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes true
```

Is there a better way to do it than this?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: I don't think you can do much better (since you cannot store reference (ref) in a field). Maybe just use try-finally without additional complications?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`IEditableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. It does not solve your problem but it does line up with your use case nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `using` use a lambda. SO you get code like this

```
ValueWrapper<bool> fred = new ValueWrapper<bool>(true);

Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes true

ScopedBackup.Do<bool>(ref fred, false, ()=>{

    Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes false
});

Debug.WriteLine(fred.Value); // writes true
```

(The code is a rough sketch, but I hope you get the idea). The reason to do this is that the caller can choose to not use `using`, its optional. Here there is no choice